# jQuery.fn.autoResize and Return Key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following library: 
https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery.fn.autoResize
for changing the dimension of textarea box.

```
$('textarea').autoResize();
```

By default the `Return key` in the textarea generate a new line.
How can I disable the autoResize on the `Return key` action?

Actually I use the `Return key` to trigger another action:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        alert("Handler for .keypress('enter') called.");
   }
});
```

but at the same time I would like to disable the autoResize just on `enter keypress`.

I did try the following code, but it does not work:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        alert("Handler for .keypress('enter') called.");
        event.stopPropagation();
   }
}); 


  $('textarea').autoResize({
     onBeforeResize: function(event){
         console.log('Before');
         event.stopPropagation();
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` if the handler for autoResize is attached directly to the textarea.

And given **stopImmediatePropagation**, you will need to make sure your event handler is registered before the autoResize.